# Multiples Spawn Session with expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to do one only script for connect by ssh to several devices (sometimes three devices, other times ten, ....) and execute the same commands in them.

#### For example:

If I execute `./script.sh ipaddress1 ipaddress2 ipaddress5`
I want to do one ssh to all devices (ipaddress 1, 2 and 5),to execute one command and close session. But my problem is that only I can connect to the first device. How can I do by do one loop until I will connect to the last device?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set list_ip [lindex $argv 0]

foreach ip $list_ip {
spawn ssh -l NA $ip
  expect "password:"
  send "pepe\n"
  expect "#"
  exp_send "sh linecard all\n\r"
  send "\n"
  send "exit\n"
  send "\n"

expect eof
}
expect "%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, simple. Walk over the `argv` list (all arguments), not over the first argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
foreach ip $argv {
    spawn ssh -l NA $ip
    expect "password:"
    send "pepe\n"
    expect "#"
    exp_send "sh linecard all\n\r"
    send "\n"
    send "exit\n"
    send "\n"

    expect eof
}
```